# convert excelsheet to work book in c#

Tags: c#

i have  three  excel  files like this place at this location.

```
string  path1=@"D:\\report\test1.xls";
string  path2=@"D:\\report\test2.xls";
string  path3=@"D:\\report\test3.xls";
```

now i need to copy all these excel files into 1 workbook.and save the workbook under this 
path

string strWorkPath=@"E:\report";
can anyone tell me  how  to achive this in C#,look  for  some  code  snippnets that can help me out.
 i am new  to this  excel opeartion.

any help  would be  great.

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840310/how-to-export-excel-worksheets-into-new-workbooks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Excel library, heres some examples of how to do it:

[How to copy one worksheet to another WorkBook](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/b87bd31c-eb1a-4d6b-89de-a3ee4485b0c8)

[Excel Copy WorkSheet Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.copy%28VS.80%29.aspx)

[Excel Interop Use](http://dotnetperls.com/excel-interop)