# Closing Excel.exe process

Tags: vb.net, excel

The code below works, but the excel.exe process still runs even though I quit Excel. I am using Office 2013 and referencing the correct import for `Office.Interop.Excel`

Am i missing something

```
Sub demo()
    Dim xls As New Excel.Application
    Dim book As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    xls.Workbooks.Open("Test.xlsx")
    book = xls.ActiveWorkbook
    oSheet = book.ActiveSheet   

    oSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "testing"

    book.Save()
    book.Close()
    xls.Workbooks.Close()
    xls.Quit()

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oSheet)
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(book)
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xls)
    oSheet = Nothing
    book = Nothing
    xls = Nothing
    GC.Collect()
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try the solution in this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435898/vb-net-excel-program-leaves-excel-exe-floating-after-completion?rq=1 ?

Comment: Hey Matt, tried that but getting a error 'Object ref not set to an instance of an object'

Comment: This code works for me although it takes a couple of seconds before it dissappears out of task manager

Comment: Dont no if this is relevant.  but when i close down visual studio the exe goes away.  did some debugging and everything seems to be fine.....

Comment: This code also works for me but it does take a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having issues with it, have you tried to just kill the process?

```
 Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("name");
foreach (Process proc in procs)
    proc.Kill();
```

Not sure if it will work how you want, but it is an idea.

Answer (score 0):

call                 `TryKillProcessByMainWindowHwnd(hWnd);`         after `GC.Collect()` and implementation of the method:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);
        public static bool TryKillProcessByMainWindowHwnd(int hWnd)
        {
            uint processID;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId((IntPtr)hWnd, out processID);
            if (processID == 0) return false;
            try
            {
                Process.GetProcessById((int)processID).Kill();
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()` - the better approach is to call the .NET Garbage Collector to clean up by calling `GC.Collect()`.

You have to be careful to ensure that the code talking to Excel is not in the same method as your `GC.Collect()`, else the debugger might keep objects alive longer than you'd expect.

The general pattern would be:

```
Sub WrapperThatCleansUp()

    ' NOTE: Don't call Excel objects in here... 
    '       Debugger would keep alive until end, preventing GC cleanup

    ' Call a separate function that talks to Excel
    DoTheWork()

    ' Now Let the GC clean up (twice, to clean up cycles too)
    GC.Collect()    
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    GC.Collect()    
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

End Sub

Sub DoTheWork()
    Dim xls As New Excel.Application
    Dim book As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    xls.Workbooks.Open("Test.xlsx")
    book = xls.ActiveWorkbook
    oSheet = book.ActiveSheet   

    oSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "testing"

    book.Save()
    book.Close()
    xls.Workbooks.Close()
    xls.Quit()

    ' NOTE: No calls the Marshal.ReleaseComObject() are ever needed
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that works on an excel file 2010, the only code I use and closes the excel file is `dim workbook  As Excel.Workbook`  => `workbook.Close()`but i don't close the excel application or all workbooks. try it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)